# Pop OS alt + f4 not working for specific applications

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I have recently installed Pop OS 18.04 but have a weird problem. I want to close some applications ([File manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files), [Gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/), and [Slack](https://slack.com/release-notes/linux)) using **Alt+f4**. However this doesn't seem to work.If I try to close other applications (such as Google Chrome) with **Alt+f4** everything works as expected.

I am running Pop!-OS 18.04 LTS on GNOME 3.28.2 .

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was this:  The default command for closing applications is Super+W.I had to change it to Alt + f4

Comment: In my case the default was `super + q`

Answer (score 1):

It's Super(Windows) + Q on Pop!_OS. I don't know if you find it, but maybe this post could help someone. PD(Sorry for my english, it's not my native language).